# How to call a React Hook from a child component to refresh results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, callback, react-hooks

I'm trying to refresh the results on the page, but the refresh button is in a child component to where my React Hook is originally called.

```
export const ParentComponent = ({

}) => {
  const infoINeed = useSelector(getInfoINeed);

  const { error, isLoading, data } = useMyAwesomeHook(infoINeed.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Body className={classes.body}>
        <div>Hello Stack overflow</div>
      <Body>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My Awesome hook looks like this

```
export const useDogCounts = (name: string | undefined) => {
  const { data: token, error: authError } = useAuthHook();
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyData = async () => {
      const request = myRequest(name);

      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const counts = callMyFunction()
        setMyData(counts);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (requestError) {
        if (requestError === null) {
          setError(requestError);
        } else {
          throw requestError;
        }

        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchMyData();
  }, [name, token]);


  return {
    data: dogCounts,
    error,
    isLoading,
  };
};
```

then in my `<Header/>` component, I have a refresh button that I want to call the hook.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = ({}) => {


  return (
    <Page.Header className={classes.headerWrapper}>
          <Page.Title>Dog Counts</Page.Title>
               <Button
                  onClick={() => {}} // functionality to go here
                >
                  Refresh
                </Button>
             
    </Header>
  );
};
```

I've tried a couple approaches, including passing a variable into the useDogCount hook called `refresh`, which the Header component changes in the state in order to trigger the useEffect hook in my main hook. It seemed a bit messy to do it this way and introduce a new variable to keep track of.

I also have implemented something like this elsewhere a different time where I did not use a `useEffect` hook inside my custom hook, and instead passed the Promise back to the required place to refresh it. However, I need the useEffect hook here to check for updating `name` or `token`.

Comment: where does the function `setMyData` comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the function used to fetch the data from your custom hook :

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
  const infoINeed = useSelector(getInfoINeed);

  const { error, isLoading, data, fetchData } = useMyAwesomeHook(infoINeed.name);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header onClickRefresh={fetchData}/>
      <Body className={classes.body}>
        <div>Hello Stack overflow</div>
      <Body>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
export const useDogCounts = (name: string | undefined) => {
  const { data: token, error: authError } = useAuthHook();
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    ... // code to fetch the data
  }, [name, token]);

  useEffect(fetchData, [fetchData]);

  return {
    data: dogCounts,
    fetchData,
    error,
    isLoading,
  };
};
```

```
export const Header: FC<HeaderProps> = ({onClickRefresh}) => {
  return (
    <Page.Header className={classes.headerWrapper}>
      <Page.Title>Dog Counts</Page.Title>
        <Button onClick={onClickRefresh}>
          Refresh
        </Button>
    </Header>
  );
};
```

Comment: If I restructure my hook like this, I'm getting the error: `The 'fetchData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'fetchData' in its own useCallback() Hook.` This is surprising because name and token should stay the same. I'll try this structure and add the useCallback()

Comment: you can use `useCallback` to memoize the `fetchData` function

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no connection between your hook and either of components in terms of firing the request for the data. What I would suggest is to add a function to your hook that is going to call your api and return that function from the hook

```
export const useDogCounts = (name: string | undefined) => {
  const { data: token, error: authError } = useAuthHook();
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 const callAnApi = async () => {
  // ... body of the useEffect
 }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyData = async () => {
      const request = myRequest(name);

      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const counts = callMyFunction()
        setMyData(counts);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (requestError) {
        if (requestError === null) {
          setError(requestError);
        } else {
          throw requestError;
        }

        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchMyData();
  }, [name, token]);


  return {
    data: dogCounts,
    error,
    isLoading,
  };
};
```

then in your `ParentComponent` you can destructure it as

```
const { error, isLoading, data, callAnApi } = useMyAwesomeHook(infoINeed.name);
```

and pass it to `Header` component as prop where you just use it as

```
<Button
  onClick={callAnApiHandler}
>
  Refresh
</Button>
```

Then you could call this new function inside your `useEffect` for further refactor